# Is there a way to use custom icon for material ui's pagination

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

Is there a way to use a custom icon for pagination in material ui?

[Material UI Pagination Documentation](https://material-ui.com/components/pagination/) ,
[CodeSandbox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/bn7nw)

I would like to change the default left and right chevron (for navigation)

[image]

Is there a way to achieve this using material ui's existing component?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you cant change only the icon directly but you can customize complete pagination using [`usePagination`](https://material-ui.com/components/pagination/#usepagination)

[image: Edit Material demo]

```js
<ul className={classes.ul}>
  {items.map(({ page, type, selected, ...item }, index) => {
    let children = null;

    if (type === 'start-ellipsis' || type === 'end-ellipsis') {
      children = '…';
    } else if (type === 'page') {
      children = (
        <IconButton  style={{ 
          fontWeight: selected ? 'bold' : undefined, 
         backgroundColor: selected ? 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04)' : 'white',
          width: 50, 
          height:50
        }} {...item}>
          {page}
        </IconButton >
      );
    } else {
      children = (
        <IconButton  {...item}>
          {type === 'previous' ? <FastRewindIcon/> : <FastForwardIcon/>}
        </IconButton >
      );
    }
    return <li key={index} style={{ margin: 'auto 0'}}>{children}</li>;
  })}
</ul>
```

Comment: could i just ask you how i could manipulate the pages though? I initially thought of just putting a onClick event handle on <li>  like <li onClick={//fetch api data for clicked index page} key={index} but then the fastrewindicon wont work.

Comment: you can use all properties inside the `usePagiantion` like this 
```js
const { items } = usePagination({
    count: 10,
    onChange: (event,page) => console.log(page)
  });
```